# Method help- beginners mistakes

Tags: java, class, enums, interface

```
import java.util.*;

public class Problem5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Number();
    }
}

public int Number() {
    System.out.println("please enter a one digit number");
    int placeholder = scanner.nextInt;
    return placholder;
}
```

I'm having a lot of trouble writing methods in terms of the method signature.

The errors I'm getting typically involve  "error: class, interface, or enum expected" on the receiving or returning types.

In this case, the errors are on the returning aspect in the method signature and then later within the method when trying to return an int.

Can anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Learn to indent your code. It helps everybody who has to read it - that includes us, but more importantly, it includes *you*.

Comment: number() function must be static to be called in the main function

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would reformat the code in a question, but since half of your problem is caused by the fact that the code is not indented, I will reformat it in my answer.

**Here's your code reformatted**:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Number();
    }
}
public int Number()
{
    System.out.println("please enter a one digit number");
    int placeholder = scanner.nextInt;
    return placholder;
}
```

Now it is easy to see that your `Number()` method is not inside the class definition.

Also, to call your `Number()` method from a static method, you need to make your `Number()` method static also.

And thirdly, you need to pass the scanner variable into your `Number()` method.

**Here's the resulting fix**:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Number(scanner);
    }

    public static int Number(Scanner scanner)
    {
        System.out.println("please enter a one digit number");
        int placeholder = scanner.nextInt;
        return placholder;
    }
}
```

**Edit** Lastly, as @AndyTurner and @javaguy point out, use Java naming standards - variables and method names start with a lower case letter.

Comment: And fourthly, use Java naming conventions (`Number` -> `number`).

Comment: Agreed, that is good practice, but in this case it won't resolve any compilation issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write methods **outside the `class` definition**, which you could not spot because of poor indentation of the code, so add your `Number()` method inside your `Problem5` class as shown below:

```
public class Problem5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Number(scanner);
    }
    public static int Number(Scanner scanner)  {
         System.out.println("please enter a one digit number");
         int placeholder = scanner.nextInt;
         return placholder;
    }
}
```

Also, note that `Number()` method should be `static` in order call it from `static main()` method. Also, you need to **pass the `scanner` object to the `Number()` method as an argument** (shown above).

---

As a side note, ensure that you follow Java naming standards i.e., method names start with lowercase like `number()`, but not like `Number()`